# Jspdf 2.5.1 doc.addFileToVFS is not a function

Tags: fonts, jspdf

I want utf8 greek characters in my pdf.I have a custom font in base 64.

I use the addFileToVFS but it says it's not a function.I have also tried using the font converter but to no use.

If it helps i use cdn for the library

Edit:
Kj's solution did the trick! Turns out my problem was that I was using jspdf.umd.min.js.
Many tutorials I saw used this approach:

```html
<!-- Include jsPDF library -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

But after changing to jspdf.umd.js everything works as expected!

```html
  <!-- Include jsPDF library -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.js"></script>
```

A big thanks to KJ for helping!I am new to stack overflow but this was a great exprerience.Ps:Sorry for my initial post lacking details i learned from that and i will be more detailed in the future.Have a nice day.

Comment: Hello,I have the exact same setup with the link you provided.But unfortunately it produces the same error as in the title:pub sub error pdf.addFileToVFS is not a function! I was wondering if there some version specific problem?

Comment: Hey man thanks for trying to help.I don't have access to the code right now.I will provide a better example tomorrow,and make it easier to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use "Default" PDF Greek as symbols in jsPDF without a font. However I do NOT recommend it, as slow to sort out spacing of back feeds for accents and a nightmare unless you have a custom key mapper.

[image]

Depending on how you source your preferred custom font (as a ttf) it needs to be embedded inside the page before convert to replace those PDF symbols.  What we need is a mapping from PDF keyboard numeri's "ToUnicode" as provided in a good TTF file.

Commonly DeJaVu or Noto font is suggested but any with good Greek alphabet should work. Here I selected Rounded_Elegance  and [submitted for conversion to JS](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/fontconverter/fontconverter.html). **Pick UMD or ES to match your js.PDF lib.**

[image]

Now we set the text in HTML, with the converted font.js in same folder (There are several other ways) this is usually the simplest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML><head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="jspdf.umd.js"> // Here local but can be CDN </script>
  <script src="Rounded_Elegance-normal.js"> // Here we have the font in same folder </script>

  Click me

    <script>
    window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    //confirm stored font is to be used
    doc.addFont('Rounded_Elegance-normal.ttf', 'Greekish', 'normal'); // choose a shorter name

    doc.setFont("Greekish", "normal"); // set custom font from here onwards
    doc.setFontSize(40);
    doc.text("Γεια σας κόσμος!", 50, 50);

    doc.save("a4.pdf"); // will save the file in the current working directory
</script></body></html>
```

Hmm perhaps not as Elegant as Promised but it works.
[image]